# Creating workbook based on two cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook "Report.xlsx" where in i have 70 sheets (The name of all 70 sheets are present on a list in a workbook called "list.xlsx"). now i need to create workbook based on a list present in "list.xlsx".

I have a list some what like this.

```
Sheet Name  Person name
Fax            Tom
Tax            Tami
Rax            Tom
Max            Sara
Sax            Tom
```

What i need is a code which can move the sheets of workbook "Report.xlsx" and create another workbook based on the above list
For Eg:

Fax, Rax & Sax should be copied to a new workbook from "Report.xlsx" and renamed it as Tom.
like wise Tax should be copied to a new workbook and renamed it as Tami.
and same Max should be copied to a new workbook and renamed it as Sara.

Thanks for all your help in advance.

---

Dear Team,

Below is the code what i tried, but i am still unable to get what i needed, can anyone help on this.

```
Sub Copysheets()
Dim thisWB  As String
Dim newWB As String
Dim endofprocess As String
Dim m As Integer
        thisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        On Error Resume Next
         Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Sheets("tempsheet").Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        On Error GoTo 0
        Sheets.Add
        ActiveSheet.Name = "tempsheet"
        Sheets("list").Select
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
            Cells.Select
            On Error Resume Next
            ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
            On Error GoTo 0
    End If
    Columns("A:C").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("tempsheet").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Columns("b").Delete
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
        If (Cells(1, 1) = "") Then
            LastRowx = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
            If LastRowx <> Rows.Count Then
                Range("A1:A" & LastRowx - 1).Select
                Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
            End If
        End If

    Cells.Select
    Selection.Sort _
            Key1:=Range("b2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, _
            MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

    lMaxSupp = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For suppno = 2 To lMaxSupp
    Windows(thisWB).Activate
    supname = Sheets("tempsheet").Range("B" & suppno)


        If supname <> "" Then
        Workbooks.Add
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "Balance Sheet Review - " & supname
            newWB = "Balance Sheet Review - " & supname
        Windows("Balance Sheet Review Dec 13 - APJ.xlsm").Activate

For i = 2 To 100

Windows(""Report.xlsx"").Activate
Worksheets("tempsheet").Activate
            FldrName = Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, 30)
            Worksheets(FldrName).Activate

            Sheets(FldrName).Select

           Sheets(FldrName).Copy Before:=Workbooks( _
        newWB & ".xlsx").Sheets(1)



Next i


        End If

    Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to put the following code into your list.xlsx.  The code you've wrote does not seems to do it so I rewrite the whole thing:

```
Sub Test()
Dim twb As Workbook
Dim nwb As Workbook
Dim rpt As Workbook
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim bcnt As Integer
Dim wbn As String
Dim wsn As String
Dim wsexist As Boolean
Dim createnwb As Boolean
Dim SFile as string
Dim Spath as string


Set twb = ThisWorkbook ' list.xlsx
Set tws = twb.Sheets("list") ' assume your worksheet called list in list.xlsx

Spath = "C:\" ' or where your source files stored
SFile = Dir(Spath & "*.xlsx") 
do while len(Sfile) > 0
Set rpt = Workbooks.Open(Spath & SFile) 'or where the file sits

twb.Activate
tws.Activate

Range("A1", Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Select
bcnt = Selection.Count
Selection.Sort _
            Key1:=Range("b2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, _
            MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal


For i = 2 To bcnt
    wbn = Cells(i, 2).Value
    wsn = Cells(i, 1).Value
    wsexist = False
    createnwb = False
    If Cells(i, 2).Value <> Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
        createnwb = True
    End If

    rpt.Activate
    For Each sh In Worksheets
        If sh.Name = wsn Then
            If createnwb = True Then
                Set nwb = Workbooks.Add()
            End If
            'rpt.Activate
            sh.Copy before:=nwb.Sheets(1)
            wsexist = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sh
    twb.Activate
        If wsexist = True Then
            If Cells(i, 2).Value <> Cells(i + 1, 2).Value Then
            nwb.SaveAs Filename:="C:\" & wbn
            nwb.Close
            End If
        End If

Next i
SFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

**Customize** with your local path / file name and such.  It is based on your sample where **sheet name** sits at column A (with a col header) and **Person (workbook) name** sits at column B (with a col header)

Comment: Thanks Alex, How ever i still have one small problem, Workbooks are been created even if it is not in "Report.xlsx". I mean if there is a sheet name in List.xlsx say "Jerry" but the sheet "Jerry" do not exist in "Report.xlsx" it is creating Blank workbook, can we avoid doing that.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alex, One more thing say i have 10 report.xlsx files(like rpt1.xlsx, rpt2.xlsx...so on) in a folder is there a possibility to loop these files one by one and do the above thing. I mean Instead of defining the workbook name "Set rpt = Workbooks.Open("C:\Report.xlsx")" can it be made to loop across all the files in the folder and do the same thing.

Comment: Please find edited code.  You should also google on how it's done.  I have been warned that Stackoverflow is for help with coding issue, not writing code for free, thanks